# Using enums instead of strings speedup?

Tags: c#

I have game and I mark the states with names. On each update working with states means, you work with their names, strings. I was wondering if it is worth it to replace the strings with enum values?

Maybe it sounds dumb, but there are a lot of states and each one is processed at least 30 times per second.

Thanks

Comment: Have you profiled the app?  Is this a real issue or just a perceived one?  Ints are faster than strings but I'd probably profile the app to see if there's a bottleneck.  As a follow-up, I avoid string comparisons when something better/faster will do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, are you having performance issues?

Certainly using integer values will be faster, but if as implemented it's fast enough, spend time elsewhere. Maybe leave yourself a todo in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

By default, enums are internally treated as `int`s, so if you are checking many times then it is faster.  However, if its only being checked 30 times a second, this cost is meaningless compared to other probable costs.  Have you profiled to see what is slowest?

Comment: [Not quite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx): _The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong._

Comment: from your link: "The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int."  You explicitly have to force it to use another storage class

Comment: This is not what your first sentence states, however.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think for maximum and probably unnecessary efficiency you should consider bit flags. These allow you to do the standard bitwise operators.

```
[Flags]
enum Choices
{
    OptionOne = 0x0,
    OptionTwo = 0x1    
}

class MyClass
{
    Choices mychoice = Choices.OptionOne | Choices.OptionTwo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums are certainly cleaner in this instance and provide better maintainability... you're not going to typo a status that way (or you might, but the compiler will tell you).  It's also going to be faster, doing a simple integer comparison over a string comparison.

That being said, if the coding is already done, and you're not having performance problems specific to this implementation of status, there's not much of a reason to change it.  As others have said, profile it if that's your only issue.